# TSQL: Different execution due to parallelism

Tags: sql-server-2012

One of my query is performing slow for small records but for large records its working as expected.
Foe example:

Query #1

```
SELECT * 
FROM vwServwerHealthReport 
WHERE startDate >= '20/02/2018' 
  AND startDate <= '06/03/2018'
```

-- fetching more than 6000 records in 0:02 seconds

Query #2

```
SELECT * 
FROM vwServwerHealthReport 
WHERE startDate >= '02/03/2018' 
  AND startDate <= '06/03/2018'
```

-- fetching approx 800 records in 02:05 seconds

I have checked execution plans as well and found that the execution plans of both the queries is different and the slow running query is using parallelism operator a lot but the fast query is not using any parallelism operation.

Initially I was assuming this to be a parameter sniffing problem and implemented "Recompile, Optimize for" hints but have not got the improvement.

Please let me know why parallelism is being used by slow running query even for small records and how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: You could try to use hint `MAXDOP(1)` or start playing with [cost threshold for parallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-cost-threshold-for-parallelism-server-configuration-option)

Comment: Thanks @lad2025 for your response, I shall implement your suggestion and shall update you with results.Just willing to understand that, why for one query, optimizer has used parallelism that too for small set of records.

Comment: Do you have an index on `startDate`? How messy/complex is `vwServwerHealthReport`? And why is there a typo in your view name? ;)

Comment: If you right click on your server > properties > advanced you'll likely see that the cost for threshold for parallelism is 5 and the max degree is 0. This is a default. [Brent Ozar has a good post on this...](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/why-cost-threshold-for-parallelism-shouldnt-be-set-to-5/)

Comment: Yes @BradC, we have index on startDate and definition of vwServerHealthReport is simple with couple of joins. Yes, their is typo in view name :)